# Concurrent testing in karate

Tags: karate

I am using karate for automating the things in my project and I am so much exited to say that the way karate gives solutions on API testing. I have a requirement in my project where I need to check the effect on the system when multiple users are performing the same task at the same time(exactly same time including fraction of seconds). I want to identify the issues like deadlock, increased response time, application crashes etc... using this testing. Give me a glint that how can I get concurrent testing solution in karate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is something called `karate-gatling`, please read: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-gatling